# Javascript redirect on 404 error

Tags: javascript

There is an external website which contains an html document for each day of the year, and I am trying to automatically load the document for the current date. However, the urls are not consistent across every document. Some of them end with `.html` while others end with `.htm`, and some of them might have a letter appended to the filename.

What I want to do is attempt to load a url, and if it results in a 404 error, try loading a different url.

For example, I might do `window.location.replace(baseurl+'.htm');`
and if that results in a 404 error, attempt `window.location.replace(baseurl+'.html');` and if that results in a 404, try something else.

How can I determine when the server sends a 404 error and attempt to load a new url?

Comment: You can try with XHR before actually redirecting. Once you've redirected, your code will stop running and you're powerless to do anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function where you can pass in extensions to try, and it returns the first valid URL to a callback:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var extensions = ['.html', '.htm'];
var count = 0;
var baseurl = 'http://blah.com/file';

function validUrl(baseurl, cb) {
  request.open('GET', baseurl + extensions[count], true);

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
      if (request.status === 200) {
        cb(baseurl + extensions[count]);
      } else {
        count++;
        if (count === extensions.length) {
          cb(false);
        } else {
          validUrl(baseurl, cb);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  request.send();
}

// usage:

validUrl(baseurl, function(url) {
  if (url) {
    // use the valid url
  } else {
    console.log('no valid urls');
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like this would work perfectly, but I get Cross-Origin Request Blocked from the server I am trying to read from, so I'll have to figure out something else I suppose.

Comment: If they aren't on the same domain, you would have to use JSONP, have the server set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, or use [some other method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Answer (score 1):

As @Siguza said you can persist as an asynchronous request and validate it's status.

I suggest you to create a function which calls an AJAX and handle it's status returning to you if it's OK or not as a boolean. Something like:

```
// I'm  building an function to validate the URL
function checkValidURL(url) {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for older browsers
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  // Callback
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      return true; // OK
    } else { // or -> } else if (this.status == 404) {
      return false; // Ops, something happen..
    }
  };
  // AJAX configuration
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false); // <- "false" for a synchronous request
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Simple example of use:

```
if (!checkValidURL("http://www.my_url")) {
    console.log("invalid URL"); 

    // Call or check other URL
} else {
    // It's OK, proceed with the business rules
}
```

Functions can wait AJAX requests by setting asynchronous "false", like: [Is there any way to wait for AJAX response and halt execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615169/is-there-any-way-to-wait-for-ajax-response-and-halt-execution)

Comment: This isn't going to work because the function will return before the AJAX resolves.

Comment: Updated, my fault synchronous was true.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the code is good, but I am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked error, so I might need to rethink my approach here.

Comment: Your function still returns before `xmlhttp.send()` does.

Comment: You're welcome @Zarxrax, I suggest you to take a look into questions about CORS + xmlHttpRequest like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272611/make-cors-ajax-requests-using-xmlhttprequest and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400594/understanding-xmlhttprequest-over-cors-responsetext .. hope it could help you