# How to pass AJAX success into another function with parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

In my blade, I got this script:-

```
function itemDetails(item_id){

    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: './itemDetails/'+item_id,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(response){

                $('#modalTitle').text(response.data.name);
                $('#modalID').text(response.data.id);
                }
            });
    }
```

I have another function which I call it when user clicks on the button with parameter,

```
function currentItem(id, itemAvailability, maxItem){}
```

Now, how do I call the results in AJAX success into my `currentItem`, because i need to store all the data in a new array called `items[]`. Can anyone help me T-T

This is the json output incase you need to see:

```
"data": {
    "name": "Fried Chicken Wings",
    "id": 99,
    "price": "$13.00",
    "options": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "item_id": 99,
            "name": "Size",
            "options": "small,medium"
        }
    ],
    "has_variants": true,
    "description": "Fried Chicken Wings"
},
"status": true,
"errMsg": ""
}
```

Comment: As , you already have array `items[]` simply push this new value inside it .

Comment: Hi, we meet again lol i feel dumb ;_; how can i push the new value?

Comment: Using `.push()` ? Also, if you need that result immediately inside your calling function you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615578/10606400) suggestion .

Comment: oh yess, already push it into new array, but whenever i click the button, the array will be added instead of displaying new array for new id, how can i fix that?

Comment: Please elaborate more .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234018/discussion-between-swati-and-cdogol).

Answer (score 1):

1: you can declare a global variable and store success data in that, After that you can get that variable data in currentItem function.

2: another option is that you can save data in localStorage and then get data from localstorage in currentItem function.